# foreign key relationship, in that the reference table (foreign key table) is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I see a foreign key relationship, in that the reference table (foreign key table) is null but it has foreign value key. So what type of constraint it is? 
EX:

```
ALTER TABLE XXXXX.XXXXXXXX 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ABCDEF) 
REFERENCES null (null);
```

DB: Oracle.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this syntax in Oracle 11g. Is this some new feature in Oracle 12c?

Comment: Is that the result of running a script in some language (PL/SQL, Java etc.) It's most definitely not going to be accepted by the Oracle engine.